# Flutter - no colors.dart for cupertino theme?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Why is there no `Colors` package for Cupertino theme?

One can easily use `Colors.green` while `Material` package is imported. Where are Flutter color constants stored for Cupertino theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use Cuppertino's color constants.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

Container(
  color: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
  child: Text("USER"),
)
```